# How to find the kernel of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

> How to find the kernel of the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3}$ given by $T(x,y,z)=(x,2y,0)$?

I do not quite understand how to do this!

and

> How to find the kernel of the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ given by $T(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: What do you mean by number? Also, the notation in the second question is unusual and it defines a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: shouldnt you have 3x3 matrix instead?

Comment: How to find the core? You mean "the kernel"?

Comment: yes, I not speak Englhis,

Comment: The kernel of the transformation is the set of vectors it maps to $0$. Can you find that? What is the number of a transformation?

Answer (score 1):

To find the kernel of the first linear transformation, you must determine for which $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ we have $T(x,y,z)=(0,0,0).$ I will leave that to you.

For the second linear transformation, we must determine $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ for which $T(x,y,z)=(0,0).$ In particular, note that $$T(x,y,z)=(x+z,2x-y+z),$$ so we need $x+z=0$ and $2x-y+z=0.$ The first equation holds precisely when $z=-x,$ so the second equation becomes $x-y=0$ by substitution, which means $y=x$. Hence, we are talking about the set of vectors of the form $(x,y,z)=(x,x,-x)=x(1,1,-1).$ Your kernel, then, is the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ generated/spanned by $(1,1,-1)$.