# Standard matrix of linear transformation given kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I refer to the questions listed below.

> [Find linear transformation given kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752036/find-linear-transformation-given-kernel)
>
> [How to find the kernel of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522878/how-to-find-the-kernel-of-a-linear-transformation-t-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr3?rq=1)

gniourf-gniourf gave a good and comprehensive explanation on how to derive the linear transformation from a given kernel by solving a system of linear equations, which yields:

$$\forall (x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4,\quad (x,y,z,t)=(-z+t)u+(4z-3t)v+(x+z-t)e_1+(y-2z+t)e_2.$$

Then, selecting $e_1$ and $e_2$, the linear transformation may derived:

$$\forall(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4,\quad F(x,y,z,t)=(x+z-t,y-2z+t,0)$$

However, I do not understand why $e_1$ and $e_2$ are chosen and not $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a four-dimensional vector space so needs exactly four linearly independent vectors to form a basis. Recall that any vector in  $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in its basis. So gniourf-gniourf is writing $(x,y,z,t)$ as a linear combination of the vectors $u,v,e_1$ and $e_2$.